# can I use Paypal SDK directly in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, paypal

my next project is an online booking application. I want to use Paypal as the payment gateway.  is it compulsory to develop the app through In-app purchase? can I use Paypal SDK directly?

Comment: you can only use inapp purchase

Comment: That's not correct. he has many options available to him. See the marked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're selling. If you're selling digital content that's used on the device (i.e. new content, enhanced features) then you have to use In App Purchase. Sales in the "real world" are not covered by that so you can use paypal sdk for these. In your case, I think you can go with paypal.